# AspectFit not working for Image saved to Android Device

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an issue displaying an image on Android. The issue does not exist in IOS.

My screen displays information including an image.

Sometimes the image is from a drawable (which always works) and other times it is from an image that is saved to the device into the folder `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` for Android and `Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources` for IOS.

I have found that when the image is from a file saved to the device, it does not display correctly on Android. It appears to be tiny.

So in short the issue only occurs on Android for images saved to the device.  Drawables are fine.

It's the **retailerImage**

Here is the relevant XAML...

```
<ContentView x:Name="mainView" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonNavTemplate}">
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" RowSpacing="20" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <!--<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>-->
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="categoryImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>

                <Frame x:Name="retailerImageFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                       Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End">
                    <Image x:Name="retailerImage" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
                </Frame>
...
...
```

and the portion of the code which sets the image source...

```
    categoryImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(ImageService.GetSpendCategoryImagePath(this.retailer.SupplierCategoryId));
    var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(this.retailer.ImageFromAssets);
```

As I said, it's OK on IOS so I'm hoping I do not have to change too much but I have been tinkering for a couple of days now and cannot seem to get the image to appear the same in all instances.

Any ideas and thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the image getting crunched from above and below is what you mean?

Comment: Hard to tell.On my Galkaxy S6 its just an indistinguishable square about 3mm.
I can just about tell that it is the correct image but obviosuly not scaled correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using other aspects?

Comment: Gewnreall the same on the Andoid emulators.
Slight variation but the common theme is that it is an image file that is NOT a drawable.
The image dimensions are the same as the drawable ones which work just fine.